# Error saving an image using PIL

Tags: python, image, save, python-imaging-library

I am trying to use the `getbbox` to crop a picture and then save it. However I keep on getting a certain error that I don't know how to fix.

The code:

```
 import ImageOps
 import Image

 im=Image.open("b1.jpg")
 invert_im = ImageOps.invert(im) # because the boundary is white so I convert it to black so I can crop the photo
 im2 =invert_im.getbbox() 
 invert_im = ImageOps.invert(im2) # invert back
 invert_im.save("b1_cropped.jpg")
```

The error I am receiving:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'save'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: getbox does not return an image and you are trying to treat it as one.

Comment: @pvg oh snap. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import ImageOps
import Image
im=Image.open("b1.jpg")
inverted = ImageOps.invert(im)
box = inverted.getbbox()
cropped_im = im.crop(box)
cropped_im.save("b1_cropped.jpg")
```

This should be the answer.